# Why was Quinlan Vos's scene cut from Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, george-lucas, deleted-scenes

I was looking through *Revenge of the Sith*'s [transcript](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html) to answer a question, and I found this:

> The Jedi QUINLAN VOS is riding on top of a CLONE TURBO TANK. The main cannon of a second tank slowly swings to point right at him and a COUPLE OF CLONES. 
>   The cannon fires, and QUINLAN VOS and the CLONES disappear in a huge EXPLOSION.

Looking on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos/Canon#Behind_the_scenes), I found this:

> The character, as fleshed out in the Expanded Universe, eventually caught Lucas' eye. The director was intrigued by Vos and decided to include him in the 2005 film *Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith*. The character was scripted to appear on the planet Kashyyyk, the Wookiee homeworld, during the execution of Order 66, but the scene was cut before the scene was shot or an actor was cast. An animatic featuring Vos was developed, however, and a passing reference to the character remained in the final film

Have any reasons been given as to why this scene was cut?

Answer (score 6):

### Likely reason - Rewrites

Couldn't find an "official" source but there was an unofficial [source](https://www.forevergeek.com/2013/06/from-eu-to-canon-9-star-wars-things-george-lucas-didnt-create/) which stated that although the character became popular and that he was *intended* to appear, the scene was cut mainly due to rewrites of the script. The following is quoted from the link provided:

> After the character gained popularity among fans, appearing in numerous comic books beyond his lengthy run in Republic, **George Lucas took a shine to the character and canonized him by writing him into *Revenge of the Sith*, though his scene was cut in rewrites.** But his name, “Master Vos,” is still mentioned by Obi-Wan in the film’s dialogue.

Interestingly, there was an animatic test which included Vos at 1:31:

Comment: Not sure how to set the time at 1:31 automatically...

Comment: I don't think you can set a time when embedding it this way; just make reference in your answer to watch at 1:31 and that's the best you can do!

Comment: @N_Soong - This [guy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-beat-level-3-15-in-angry-birds/3749#3749) did I think but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user35594 There you go. The time indexing only works when you use the youtu.be share link

Comment: @JasonBaker - Great, cheers!

Comment: This logic is kind of circular.  It adds up to "It was cut because it was cut."

Comment: @RogueJedi - I agree but when it comes to script writers, who can stop them? :). Would be interesting to see if there is an official source.

Comment: @user35594 My point is that this doesn't answer the question. It merely repeats information from the question that it was cut, not why it was cut.